# Rolling a function on a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have the following data frame `C`.

```
>>> C
              a    b   c
2011-01-01    0    0 NaN
2011-01-02   41   12 NaN
2011-01-03   82   24 NaN
2011-01-04  123   36 NaN
2011-01-05  164   48 NaN
2011-01-06  205   60   2
2011-01-07  246   72   4
2011-01-08  287   84   6
2011-01-09  328   96   8
2011-01-10  369  108  10
```

I would like to add a new column, `d`, where I apply a rolling function, on a fixed window (6 here), where I somehow, for each row (or date), *fix* the value `c`. One loop in this rolling function should be (pseudo):

```
              a    b   c   d
2011-01-01    0    0 NaN   a + b*2 (a,b from this row, '2' is from 'c' on 2011-01-06)
2011-01-02   41   12 NaN   a + b*2 (a,b from this row, '2' is still from 2011-01-06)
2011-01-03   82   24 NaN   a + b*2
2011-01-04  123   36 NaN   a + b*2
2011-01-05  164   48 NaN   a + b*2
2011-01-06  205   60   2   a + b*2
2011-01-07  246   72   4   
2011-01-08  287   84   6   
2011-01-09  328   96   8   
2011-01-10  369  108  10
```

After this "loop" I want to take all of these 6 calculated rows in `d` and run a function call, which in turn will return *one* value, that should be stored in another column, `e` say:

```
              a    b   c   d                               e

2011-01-01    0    0 NaN   a + b*2 ---|                   NaN
2011-01-02   41   12 NaN   a + b*2    |                   NaN
2011-01-03   82   24 NaN   a + b*2    | These values      NaN
2011-01-04  123   36 NaN   a + b*2    | are input to      NaN
2011-01-05  164   48 NaN   a + b*2    | function          NaN
2011-01-06  205   60   2   a + b*2 ---| yielding          X
2011-01-07  246   72   4                value X in
2011-01-08  287   84   6                column 'e'
2011-01-09  328   96   8   
2011-01-10  369  108  10
```

This procedure would then be iterated onto the *next* window (again 6 long) like:

```
              a    b   c   d             e
2011-01-01    0    0 NaN   
2011-01-02   41   12 NaN   a + b*4 (a,b from this row, '4' is from 'c' now from 2011-01-07)
2011-01-03   82   24 NaN   a + b*4 (a,b from this row, '4' is still from 2011-01-07)
2011-01-04  123   36 NaN   a + b*4
2011-01-05  164   48 NaN   a + b*4
2011-01-06  205   60   2   a + b*4       X
2011-01-07  246   72   4   a + b*4
2011-01-08  287   84   6   
2011-01-09  328   96   8   
2011-01-10  369  108  10

              a    b   c   d                               e

2011-01-01    0    0 NaN                                  NaN
2011-01-02   41   12 NaN   a + b*4 ---|                   NaN
2011-01-03   82   24 NaN   a + b*4    | These values      NaN
2011-01-04  123   36 NaN   a + b*4    | are input to      NaN
2011-01-05  164   48 NaN   a + b*4    | function          NaN
2011-01-06  205   60   2   a + b*4    | yielding          X
2011-01-07  246   72   4   a + b*4 ---| value Y in        Y
2011-01-08  287   84   6                column 'e'
2011-01-09  328   96   8   
2011-01-10  369  108  10
```

Hopefully this is clear enough,

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `pd.rolling_apply`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')

def foo(x, df):
    window = df.iloc[x]
    # print(window)
    c = df.ix[int(x[-1]), 'c']
    dvals = window['a'] + window['b']*c
    return bar(dvals)

def bar(dvals):
    # print(dvals)
    return dvals.mean()

df['e'] = pd.rolling_apply(np.arange(len(df)), 6, foo, args=(df,))
print(df)
```

yields

```
              a    b   c       e
2011-01-01    0    0 NaN     NaN
2011-01-02   41   12 NaN     NaN
2011-01-03   82   24 NaN     NaN
2011-01-04  123   36 NaN     NaN
2011-01-05  164   48 NaN     NaN
2011-01-06  205   60   2   162.5
2011-01-07  246   72   4   311.5
2011-01-08  287   84   6   508.5
2011-01-09  328   96   8   753.5
2011-01-10  369  108  10  1046.5
```

---

The `args` and `kwargs` parameters were [added to `rolling_apply` in Pandas version 0.14.0](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6289).

Since in my example above `df` is a global variable, it is not really necessary
to pass it to `foo` as an argument. You could simply remove `df` from the `def
foo` line and also omit the `args=(df,)` in the call to `rolling_apply`.

However, there are times when `df` might not be defined in a scope accessible by `foo`. In that case, there is a simple workaround -- make a closure:

```
def foo(df):
    def inner_foo(x):
        window = df.iloc[x]
        # print(window)
        c = df.ix[int(x[-1]), 'c']
        dvals = window['a'] + window['b']*c
        return bar(dvals)
    return inner_foo

df['e'] = pd.rolling_apply(np.arange(len(df)), 6, foo(df))
```

Comment: Seems legit, but I get
TypeError: rolling_apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'

Comment: The `args` parameter was added in Pandas version 0.14.0. I've added a workaround for earlier versions.

Comment: Your workaround works perfectly! Thanks @unutbu. I had to convert the input 'x' in the inner_foo function though, as the rolling_apply() seems to convert the np.arange object into float64 type.

Comment: @unutbu Is there any way to replicate this answer without using `pd.rolling_apply`? It seems that `DataFrame.rolling.apply` only sends the values as a numpy array to the applying function and not a Series with the index. Please see this question for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701246/how-to-get-rolling-pandas-dataframe-subsets

Comment: @TedPetrou: I like the way you [solved the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41701507/190597). Pre-calculating results which require data from multiple columns *before* calling `groupby` or `rolling/apply` often seems to be the best way to go.

Comment: @TedPetrou: However, if for some reason you need the extra flexibility of accessing multiple columns of the DataFrame from within `func`, you could use `df['newvar'] = pd.Series(range(len(df))).rolling(2, min_periods=1).apply(func, args=[df])`, where the definition of `func` is modified to take 2 arguments: `def func(x, df): x = df.iloc[x]; tmp = (x["var1"] * (x["var2"] == 74)).sum(); return tmp`.

Comment: The trick is to call `rolling` on `pd.Series(range(len(df)))` (which you later use as ordinal index values) instead of on `df` itself.

Comment: Very clever, I didn't think about rolling on the index. It seems odd that the other groupby methods pass a Series or a dataframe and rolling passes an array.